# do while loop doesn't loop even if the condition is true

Tags: loops, while-loop

This is the section that doesn't loop

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // needed to use dialog boxs

public class PalindromeDetector
{// begin class
         
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {//begin main
          String userWord, continueLoop = " ";
          int numString;
           
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program will ask the user for a string and check to see if it is a palindrome.");
                   
          do
          {//begin do while loop
             userWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a string.");
             
             if(PalORNot(userWord))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userWord + " is a palinedrome.");
             else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userWord + " is not a palinedrome.");
                
             continueLoop = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would like to try again? enter yes to try again or quit to exit.");
                                                     
          } while (continueLoop == "Yes" || coninueLoop == "yes"); //end do while loop
```

Comment: Is `coninueLoop` in the second check a typo, maybe? BTW better convert the user answer to uppercase and then check against YES only.

Comment: oh i copied that wrong. even with the continueLoop variable in the same spelling, it still doesn't loop.

Comment: Check this. You should use `continueLoop.equals("Yes")` instead of `continueLoop == "Yes"`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/260313

Comment: yes I put that and it works now thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In Java `continueLoop == "Yes"` does not work, you have to use `continueLoop.equals("yes")` to compare strings.

And you forgot the `t` in second `continueLoop` by the way.

`==` compares whether it's the same object

`.equals()` compares whether it's the same value

Comment: I did not think about it that way. thank you very much it works now.